# how to get the previous value on a subform for a existing record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Good day can someone help me figure this one out I don't think it's so complicated there is a way to do it but I can't figure it out.

I got 4 fields
ID
Opening Hours
Closing Hours
Date

for instance [Opening Hours] is 8 [Closing Hours] is 16 then my [Opening Hours] will become 16
on the new existing record by default.

I place this code on my Default value property for Opening Hours its working but not for existing records only for new records.

=Nz(DMax("[Closing Hours]","PlantTransaction"))

What must actually happen is that I already got 4 records in a subform now when I enter record one Opening Hours 8 and Closing Hours 16 record two Opening Hours must become as default 16 not record 5 because its skipping the 4 existing records and jump automatically to a new record like record 5
Thanks in advance hope one of you guys can make my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

The 'Default Value' property in Access forms only works for new records. What you need is a bit of code for doing it to both new and existing records. Something like the following should work in the subform's `Current` event:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    If IsNull(txtOpening) Then
        Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
        If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
            If Me.NewRecord Then
                rst.MoveLast
            Else
                rst.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
                rst.MovePrevious
            End If
            txtOpening = rst!Closing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The `IsNull(txtOpening)` IF statement is just to ensure you don't overwrite the opening value for the current record if it's already been entered. You can remove it if you always want it to be overwritten when the user enters the record.